# How to handle circular dependencies across multiple guice private modules?

Tags: java, guice, circular-dependency

I am currently writing some framework code that provides a blueprint for services within our platform so that service implementors can focus on the service specific logic rather than the boilerplate integration code. Dependency injection is done via guice.

The blueprint has 2 types of logical component;

1. 1 and only 1 integration component that integrates the service with the outside world (messaging middleware etc)
2. 1-n business logic components

Each logic component depends on the integration component.

The integration component depends on *all* the logic components.

Since this is framework code, the framework is not aware of any of the concrete details so it is not possible to statically declare the dependencies and form the dependency graph. I would like to avoid making service implementors do this because it means they are repeating themselves (just declaring that they have n business logic modules means they have this circular dependency).

My question is what approaches can I take to make this work **without** making service implementors write that boilerplate code?

Note that multibindings are not available here as, for various reasons outside the scope of this question, each business logic component must be a PrivateModule.

A contrived example to illustrate where

1. business logic = ModuleA, ModuleB, ModuleC
2. dependency provided by the integration = Wrapper
3. Integration's dependency on the business logic is modelled by each logic module adding something to the Wrapper

This example can be made to work by changing

```
@Provides @Exposed @Named("result")
public String go(Container in) {
    return in.format();
}
```

to

```
@Provides @Exposed @Named("result")
public String go(@Named("a") Container in, @Named("b") Container in2, @Named("c") Container in3) {
    return in.format();
}
```

i.e. by actually creating a circular dependency.

```
import com.google.inject.Exposed;
import com.google.inject.Guice;
import com.google.inject.Injector;
import com.google.inject.Key;
import com.google.inject.PrivateModule;
import com.google.inject.Provides;
import com.google.inject.Singleton;
import com.google.inject.name.Named;
import com.google.inject.name.Names;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class GuiceCircularDependencyTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Injector in = Guice.createInjector(new Owner());
        String result = in.getInstance(Key.get(String.class, Names.named("result")));
        System.out.println("Result is: " + result);
    }

    public static class Owner extends PrivateModule {
        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            bind(Container.class).in(Singleton.class);
            install(new Integration());
            install(new ModuleA());
            install(new ModuleB());
            install(new ModuleC());
            expose(String.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("result"));
        }
    }

    public static class ModuleA extends PrivateModule {

        @Override
        protected void configure() {

        }

        @Provides @Exposed @Named("a")
        public Container go(Container in, Wrapper prefix) {
            in.add(prefix + "A");
            return in;
        }
    }

    public static class ModuleB extends PrivateModule {

        @Override
        protected void configure() {

        }

        @Provides @Exposed @Named("b")
        public Container go(Container in, Wrapper prefix) {
            in.add(prefix + "B");
            return in;
        }
    }

    public static class ModuleC extends PrivateModule {

        @Override
        protected void configure() {

        }

        @Provides @Exposed @Named("c")
        public Container go(Container in, Wrapper prefix) {
            in.add(prefix + "C");
            return in;
        }
    }

    public static class Integration extends PrivateModule {
        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            bind(Wrapper.class).toInstance(new Wrapper("Module"));
            expose(Wrapper.class);
        }

        @Provides @Exposed @Named("result")
        public String go(Container in) {
            return in.format();
        }
    }

    public static class Container {
        private List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();

        public void add(String string) {
            strings.add(string);
        }

        public String format() {
            return strings.toString();
        }
    }

    public static class Wrapper {
        private final String prefix;

        public Wrapper(String prefix) {
            this.prefix = prefix;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return prefix;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Replacing the 'go()' method works for me.  What problem are you seeing?  Is Guice throwing an exception?

Comment: which go() method do you mean?

Comment: You said "This example can be made to work by changing.." I replaced the first go method with the second:  go(Container in) -> go(@Named("a") Container in, @Named("b") Container in2, @Named("c") Container in3)

Comment: ah ok, yes that is a working solution however it doesn't meet the "don't repeat yourself" requirement which is what I mean by "My question is what approaches can I take to make this work without making service implementors write that boilerplate code?". If I use this approach then I force framework users to write (not v much) such code to make the dependency graph form. I'd like to avoid this solution.

Comment: Are all the business logic components going to implement the same type(s)?

Comment: The raw type, yes. The parameterized type, it can be but doesn't have to be. i.e. I might have LogicExecutor<Trade> and LogicExecutor<ReferenceData> or I might have n different instances of LogicExecutor<Trade> that address different slices of the incoming event stream (but the events are all trades).

Comment: You may be able to accomplish this with multibindings.  I'll come up with an example: http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Multibindings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One workaround, that allows a `Multibinder` to be shared across private modules, is to wrap the `PrivateModule` in an `AbstractModule` implementation that simply installs the `PrivateModule` and binds the exposed key to the `Multibinder`

```
import com.google.inject.AbstractModule;
import com.google.inject.Exposed;
import com.google.inject.Guice;
import com.google.inject.Injector;
import com.google.inject.Key;
import com.google.inject.PrivateModule;
import com.google.inject.Provides;
import com.google.inject.multibindings.Multibinder;
import com.google.inject.name.Named;
import com.google.inject.name.Names;

import java.util.Set;

public class GuiceCircularDependencyTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Injector in = Guice.createInjector(new Owner());
        String result = in.getInstance(Key.get(String.class, Names.named("result")));
        System.out.println("Result is: " + result);
    }

    public static class Owner extends PrivateModule {
        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            Multibinder<String> multi = Multibinder.newSetBinder(binder(), String.class);
            install(new Integration());
            install(new ModuleWrapper<>(new ModuleA(), multi));
            install(new ModuleWrapper<>(new ModuleB(), multi));
            install(new ModuleWrapper<>(new ModuleC(), multi));
            expose(String.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("result"));
        }
    }

    public static class ModuleWrapper<T> extends AbstractModule {
        private final WrappablePrivateModule<T> inner;
        private final Multibinder<T> multi;

        public ModuleWrapper(WrappablePrivateModule<T> inner,
                             Multibinder<T> multi) {
            this.inner = inner;
            this.multi = multi;
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            install(inner);
            multi.addBinding().to(inner.getExposedKey());
        }
    }

    public static abstract class WrappablePrivateModule<T> extends PrivateModule {

        @Override
        protected void configure() {

        }

        public abstract Key<T> getExposedKey();
    }

    public static class ModuleA extends WrappablePrivateModule<String> {

        private static final String SUFFIX = "A";

        @Override
        public Key<String> getExposedKey() {
            return Key.get(String.class, Names.named(SUFFIX));
        }

        @Provides @Exposed @Named(SUFFIX)
        public String expose(Wrapper prefix) {
            return prefix + SUFFIX;
        }
    }

    public static class ModuleB extends WrappablePrivateModule<String> {

        private static final String SUFFIX = "B";

        @Override
        public Key<String> getExposedKey() {
            return Key.get(String.class, Names.named(SUFFIX));
        }

        @Provides @Exposed @Named(SUFFIX)
        public String expose(Wrapper prefix) {
            return prefix + SUFFIX;
        }
    }

    public static class ModuleC extends WrappablePrivateModule<String> {

        private static final String SUFFIX = "C";

        @Override
        public Key<String> getExposedKey() {
            return Key.get(String.class, Names.named(SUFFIX));
        }

        @Provides @Exposed @Named(SUFFIX)
        public String expose(Wrapper prefix) {
            return prefix + SUFFIX;
        }
    }

    public static class Integration extends PrivateModule {
        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            bind(Wrapper.class).toInstance(new Wrapper("Module"));
            expose(Wrapper.class);
        }

        @Provides @Exposed @Named("result")
        public String go(Set<String> in) {
            return in.toString();
        }
    }

    public static class Wrapper {
        private final String prefix;

        public Wrapper(String prefix) {
            this.prefix = prefix;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return prefix;
        }
    }
}
```